# Get all Categories with getGroupById in Element API plugin - Craft 3

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi

I have an endpoint created and I am getting the groupID but I am unable to get all the categories associated with the group.

This is what I have right now:

```
$categoriesGroup = Craft::$app->categories->getGroupById($catId);
```

I can't seem to get an array of entries from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$categories = Category::find()->groupId($id)->all();
```